# Требования к функциональности современного форума.

Tags: веб-программирование, design

Большенство форумов предоставляют:

- мощные средства форматирования сообщений
- удобные средства модерирования и администрирования
- гибкую систему настроек
- задатки социальных сетей - профили, друзья, прочее...
- SEO оптимизацию

Но каким должен быть **современный** форум? Каким функционалом он должен обладать? Что иметь? Чего по вашиму мнению нехватает существующим форумам?

Буду благодарен любым идеям, замечаниям и предложениям.

Comment: *мощные средства форматирования сообщений* 

ага, ббкод :)

Comment: лично мне bb-code намного удобнее, чем Markdown Syntax, хотя я его тоже уважаю, просто это разные подходы, а выбор это всегда хорошо

Comment: bbcode это по сути единственное средство форматирования, используемое на форумах, к тому я и сказал )
*Markdown Syntax* - не хочу ни кого обидеть, но... мягко говоря - ббкод лучше )

Comment: а какое по вашему самое оптимальное средство форматирования?

Comment: ББкод :) ме категорично не нравится местный редактор, когда я что то обрамляю - я должен видеть где что и как.

Answer (score 3):

Ну в первую очередь, это удобная система распределения прав пользователей.

Phpbb в этом плане сделал довольно гибко, но, к сожалению, перестарался - права можно выстраивать с разных позиций (напр. определенной группе юзеров, и к конкретному форуму), что приводит к путаннице в плане: тут все нормально, но работает не так как надо - надо копать, где же я еще мог выставить права..

в крайнем случае, даже с такой системой прав, было бы неплохо сделать систему отслеживания: врубил - и сразу видно где и что надо поправить.

Вообще, имхо писать форум == изобретать велик, но это дело вкуса :)

Comment: [данный ресурс](http://hashcode.ru/) - тоже форум, но велосипедом я бы его не назвал=)

Comment: на самом деле Хэшкод ни что иное, как конференция с хорошим разграничением прав у юзеров, и мотивацией - очками. Все это уже есть, но не в такой ярко выраженной форме.